# Vim for windows CLI installation arguments

Tags: windows, command-line, vim, powershell

I am accessing a Windows server remotely and only have a powershell CLI.  After downloading vim for windows with:

```
 Invoke-WebRequest https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim81.exe -OutFile "gvim81.exe"
```

What CLI arguments do I need to install vim?

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath gvim81.exe -PassThru -ArgumentList "/Arg1=Arg1 /Arg2=Arg2"
```

Where is a list of the available CLI installation arguments and options?

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/912203/

The Vim installer should use the `/extract:<location>` option as well.

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath gvim81.exe -PassThru -ArgumentList "/help"`  does not return anything.  Also nothing with arguments `"/h"` or  `"/?"`

Comment: Also, `Start-Process -Wait -FilePath gvim81.exe -PassThru -ArgumentList '/extract:"C:\vim\" /quiet /passive'` never finishes.